# Why does assigning a second material to part of an object appear to delete that face?

Tags: materials, shaders

I've been trying to assign a second material to the same object. After selecting the face and clicking on the assign button, it only deletes the face instead of assigning the new material. What am I not doing right?[image][image][image]

Comment: Assigning a material definitely shouldn't delete anything - something else is going on. Could you share a bit more about what you're working on, and how you got there? Perhaps share an image as well? - Showing what you're seeing when the face is "deleted".

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response. I modelled a country flag for my project, but trying to assign more than one material on it was not possible, it was only deleting the faces instead of assigning the material. I also tried a cylinder with two materials yet same result.  I just edited my question with a picture now. A quick resolution to this problem will go a long way in my project. Rgds.

Comment: Dumb question: have you assigned a transparent / alpha 0 material to the faces?

Comment: This might also sound like a weird suggestion, but try going "inside" the cylinder and seeing if you can see the color there.

Comment: @Robin Bette, thanks for ur response. But transparent/alpha 0 was considered yet same result. Christopher Bennett, thanks for ur response. Going inside the cylinder, no color is seen rather u only see thru. The faces are actually deleted.

Comment: @Robin Bette, thanks for ur response. But transparent/alpha 0 was considered yet same result. Christopher Bennett, thanks for ur response. Going inside the cylinder, no color is seen rather u only see thru. The faces are actually deleted.

Answer (score 2):

All, after trying too many options and non worked, I had to uninstall version 2.82 which I was using and installed version 2.80, that solved the whole puzzle. I'm back on my project again. Thanks to all of you that contributed in one way or the other to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed .. curious about the cause.. I don't suppose it qualifies as a bug.. hard to say without going down all the avenues.